# Find if a JSONObject contains a particular JSONARray

Tags: java, json

I am working on a spring MVC application. I am using org.json jar to deal with jsonObjects. I am trying to find if a JSONObject contains a JSON array. Can any one please help me in this:

Say i have a JSON Object:

```
{"Object":{
   "array":["",""]
}
}
```

So i want to know if array exists in that json object as some times the JSONObject will be :

```
{"Object":{
   "array11":["",""]
}
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Done any research into parsing JSON in Java? Written any code?

Comment: @rmlan yes. I know we can get the JSONArray using object.getJSONArray("ArrayName"). But right now my question is what if the object doesnt contain the array. How do we check that condition if exists. Thats my only question as we will get an exception if array is not present.

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: I am using both org.json. @rmlan

Comment: Those sorts of details are helpful in the original question. Is this Android-specific development?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i will add the details in the question. Its a spring MVC application. @rmlan

Answer (score 2):

Per the [javadocs](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/) for the `org.json` JSON library, JSONObject has an optJSONArray() method that *does not* throw an exception if the key you are targeting does not exist or the value at that key is not a JSON array. For a JSONObject "foo":

```
JSONArray array = foo.optJSONArray("array");
if (array != null) {
    // do stuff with the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.json (https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) to do this. You can simply use this code to create the JSON Object:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(String);
```

And then you can use the *isNull(String)* method to check if a value exists in the object. You can get the array using the *getJSONArray(String)* method, create a loop (such as a for loop) and loop through the array (which accepts ints instead of Strings).

Comment: Hi @DarkestCodes. Thanks for the reply. But what if the String doesnt exist in JSONObject while we call getJSONArray(String)?

Comment: You check if it does exist using the _isNull()_ method in JSONObject.